# How to delete an indelible file?

Tags: files, filesystems

I was copying a file via ssh and the connection dropped. After that, I am left with a zero-sized file which cannot be deleted. `ls` and `mc` see it, doing `rm` or `rm -f` on it succeed but do nothing to the file; `rm -vf` even says "removed", but the zero-sized file stays.

Remote host is CentOS 6.8.

When trying to edit the file, it keeps the changes, but when trying to delete, it assumes a zero size and still stays. Trying to use `chattr -i` gives `Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags`. I have no root access to the server so I cannot do `fsck` or so. No process I can see via `ps` is using it. Is there any way to delete it?

Comment: Have you tried find . -size  0 -print -delete?

Comment: Grace Thompson, tried, the result is the same.

Comment: if you lsof | grep name_of_file does it show up?

Comment: You can try with lsattr on the file so we can check whether attribute enabled on file or not

if attribute enabled then only root user or sudo user who has privilege to do they can execute

Comment: Reboot? Run e2fsck?

Comment: On your remote CentOS system, what type of filesystem is the stuck file on?

Comment: @kriukov you seem to have created two accounts: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/491725/kriukov and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/491724/kriukov. In order to comment, you need to log in with the [2nd account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/491724/kriukov), the one you used to ask the question.

Comment: Have you tried `find . -type f -name "name" -printf '%i\n' -delete`?

Comment: @NasirRiley, why would `find` be able to delete the file if `rm` isn't?

Comment: @ilkkachu Because the `find` command that I gave would delete it via the inode whereas the `rm` command that he used was run against the name. I'm only trying to rule it out.

Comment: @NasirRiley, is there some system where deleting a file by inode would actually work? While `readdir()` does give both the name and inode number, the standard `unlink()` and `unlinkat()` system calls only take names. And besides, considering the traditional filesystem structure, if you could delete a file by inode, how would that work for files with multiple hard links to them? Which one would be deleted, or would all of them be? Either way, it'd require actually _finding_ the names pointing at that inode, or would leave dangling filenames, which would be confusing and problematic too...

Comment: Grace Thompson, it gives empty output.

Artem S. Tashkinov, I don't have root access.

roaima, the filesystem is NFS (listed by df), what is "below" it, I don't know (yet?).

terdon, thank you, I asked the admins and they fixed this problem.

Nasir Riley, I tried your "find" command, but the file is still there.

Comment: @ilkkachu I understand your point. I only mentioned what I mentioned because I have run into something along the lines in the past where it did, in fact, work. Of course, I don't know all of the details here because there isn't enough information. That being said, the `find` command that I gave doesn't hurt anything and would simply rule it out.

Comment: Someone has root access, reboot.

Comment: Check if the file has some weird permissions, e.g. `ls -lZ`, `getfacl(1)`. the output should give hints at what to do next.